# Cakephp Problems with the bake script

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I have apache, php, and Mysql installed on my computer. I have added the PHP directory and C:\Apache\htdocs\cake\cake\console to my environmental variables path. When i load the path to the console on my CLI it loads cake.php then i type cake bake and it asks me for the path of my app, then database config. Now instead o f it loading the DMVC... menu it just returns to set the path and database and its like a loop. not sure what i am doing wrong.

All help appreciated

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Are you using `C:/Apache/htdocs/cake/app` for your path? Could you paste the entire output? Also, place the path to the CLI also in your environment `path` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try cd'ing to your app's directory, and then run `../cake/console/cake bake`

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your path to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3;` (I used the Wamp server, that's why mine is like that).